# Displaying php result as link

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have put together a fairly basic database driven website using PHP, Appache, and PHPMyAdmin. The site allows users to upload cad detail files in two formats. Along with the file paths, they can also upload the name of the file, the related service group, as well as the detail ID.

Basically everything is working smoothly except for the fact that i cannot seem to display the search result as a link.

The attached screen shot link below shows the current result. I would like to have the "PDF" and "DWG" show as a link instead of just a file path.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$output = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    $output .= "<br /><b>Detail ID:</b> " . $row['id'] . "<br /><br />";
    $output .= "<b>Name:</b> " . $row['name'] . "<br /><br />";
    $output .= "<b>Service Group:</b> " . $row['service'] . "<br /><br />";
    $output .= "<b>PDF:</b> " . $row['pdf'] . "<br /><br />";
    $output .= "<b>DWG:</b> " . $row['dwg'] . "<br /><br /><hr />"; 

}
```

Comment: Links require an `<a>` element. Start there.

Comment: @MattBall right, but it will work only locally... he'll need to upload it to dropbox and provide a *real* link if he wants it to be accessible to other people...

Comment: put anchor tag and your issue is solved `echo '<a href="my_issue_solved.com" >Solved </a>'`

Comment: You'd need at least the `<a>` anchor tags in your `$output`, though if you're not using IE file-path links like that may not work out well on file shares due to browser security on the file://// protocol.

Comment: i am completely familiar with the <a> tag. Just unsure how to go about using it when displaying a query result. Seems like every combination ive tried does not work.

Comment: hey , what do u mean by displaying search result as a link ?

Comment: `$output .= "<b>PDF:</b><a href=\"" . $row['pdf'] . "\">" . $row['pdf'] . "</a><br /><br />";`

Comment: Appreciate all of your help. @alfasin Locally is what i wanted. Everyone using the website is on the same local network. I was not expecting an answer this fast. Thanks to everyone. It's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    $output .= "<br /><b>Detail ID:</b> " . $row['id'] . "<br /><br />";
    $output .= "<b>Name:</b> " . $row['name'] . "<br /><br />";
    $output .= "<b>Service Group:</b> " . $row['service'] . "<br /><br />";
    $output .= "<b>PDF:</b> <a href='" . $row['pdf'] . "'>" . $row['pdf'] . "</a><br /><br />";
    $output .= "<b>DWG:</b> <a href='" . $row['dwg'] . "'>" . $row['dwg'] . "</a><br /><br /><hr />"; 

}
```

Comment: @user17753 why would it matter if its single? The filepath does not contain any single quotes so it is perfectly fine. HTML allows single or double quotes to be used, both are valid as per the specs. HTML5 even allows you to omit them as long as the value contains no spaces.

Answer (score 1):

As @Matt Ball's said, a link will need `<a>` element. I'm assuming `pdf` and `dwg` columns of your table will be contain URL's of files.

SO you should use it link this :

```
$output .= "<b>PDF:</b> "."<a href='".$row['pdf']."'>" . $row['pdf'] . "</a><br /><br />";
```

Output will be like this :

```
<b>PDF:</b> <a href="URL">URL</a><br /><br />
```